# C++ Win32 API Shell_NotifyIcon with modify flag always fails

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, notifications

I have been trying to use the Shell_Notify API of Windows for the app I am making. By using Shell_NotifyIcon, I am successfully able to add an icon to the taskbar when my app starts using the following code.

Note: None of the below methods other than TruncateTooltipText exist in my code. I type these like this so I don't have to post all of my code. My code does exactly what I have typed below though. My code is written so Shell_NotifyIcon will always be called when it should and the NOTIFYICONDATA structure is produced from one method that checks what portions of the structure should be filled in, depending on what I want updated. I'll post that method as well if it will help.

```
void AddNotificationIcon()
{
   NOTIFYICONDATA data = {sizeof(data)};
   data.uFlags = NIF_TIP | NIF_SHOWTIP | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_GUID | NIF_ICON
   data.guidItem = __uuidof(NotifyIconGuid);
   data.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER + NOTIFY_CALLBACK;
   data.hWnd = (HWND)this->winId();
   data.icon = LoadIcon(data.instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
   TruncateTooltipText("Some tooltip text.", &data)
   Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &data);

   data.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;
   Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, &data);
}
```

The above code works perfectly. Additionally, the callbacks work as well, so I receive the message in my Windows message loop when the icon is left or right clicked. However, whenever I try to either display a balloon message or even change the tooltip or any other call to Shell_NotifyIcon with NIM_MODIFY as the flag, the method fails and GetLastError returns the following message.

```
This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
```

Now after doing some googling, I learned that Shell_NotifyIcon uses SendMessageTimeout, so this reported error probably has nothing to do with why the method fails. Here is the code I use to try to modify the tooltip.

```
void ChangeTooltip()
{
   NOTIFYICONDATA data = {sizeof(data)};
   data.uFlags = NIF_TIP | NIF_SHOWTIP | NIF_GUID;
   data.guidItem = __uuidof(NotifyIconGuid);
   TruncateTooltipText("Some more tooltip text.", &data)
   Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &data);
}
```

It always fails, though it works flawlessly in the Windows API Notification Sample provided by Microsoft. The same thing happens when I try to display a balloon, as exemplified below.

```
void ShowBalloon()
{
   NOTIFYICONDATA data = {sizeof(data)};
   data.uFlags = NIF_GUID | NIF_INFO;
   data.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_INFO;
   data.guidItem = __uuidof(NotifyIconGuid);
   TruncateInfoText("This is some example text being displayed in a balloon.", &data)
   TruncateTitleText("This is the balloon title.", &data)
   Shell_NotifyIcon(NIF_MODIFY, &data);
}
```

Again, this code works perfectly in the Microsoft example, but not my program. All of my code above is almost exactly the same as the one provided by Microsoft, except every it says LoadString I actually take in a std::string, truncate it if it needs to be truncated, and then copy it into the NOTIFYICONDATA structure properly.

Note: I'll define TruncateTooltipText here so you all know what it looks like, if it helps. TruncateTitleText and TruncateInfoText are exactly the same, except they target the appropriate variables within the NOTIFYDATAICON structure.

```
bool TruncateTooltipText(string originalText, NOTIFYICONDATA* output)
    {
        //If the text inputted to display as a tooltip is too long, shorten it.
        if(originalText.length() > ARRAYSIZE(output->szTip))
        {
            originalText = originalText.substr(0, ARRAYSIZE(output->szTip) - 1);
            OutputDebugStringA("Notification Warning: Tooltip text is longer than allowed 128 characters. Tooltip text has been truncated!\n");
        }

        wstring toolText = wstring(originalText.begin(), originalText.end());

        HRESULT copyResult;
        copyResult = StringCchCopy(output->szTip, ARRAYSIZE(output->szTip), toolText.c_str());
        if(FAILED(copyResult))
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"Notification Error: Failed to copy the std::string for the tooltip to the structure string.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I am on Windows 8 Pro 64 bit and my program is a 64 Bit program.

Comment: I believe you need to supply the window handle for modify operations even if you include the guid.

Comment: The Microsoft samples don't do this but it still works in their sample. Still, I tried including a HWND for the window, and now the method returns true, but nothing actually happens. The tooltip does not change, nor does an information bubble show up.

Comment: You are not setting the uTimeout member.  Using NIF_GUID only works on Win7 and up, use hWnd + uID for earlier versions.  *Never* ignore the return value of winapi functions, be sure to assert() what LoadString returns.  And you are forgetting to call Shell_NotifyIcon() in your ShowBalloon function.

Comment: 1. The uTimeout member is deprecated as of Windows Vista.
2. I am using Windows 8, so NIF_GUID should work.
3. I'm not actually using LoadString in my code, I put that above so that the code shown above is shorter and more cohesive. I'll go ahead and put the actual code I'm using to fill the balloon title and text and tooltip text up.
4. I actually do call Shell_NotifyIcon in my program, the methods above don't actually exist in my code, though my code does pretty much exactly what is above. I'll correct that though.

Comment: So was this never solved? I'm having the same problem consistently, although intermittently (works sometimes, sometimes I get the error). Seems there should be some reason why this error description/code was written for this method and not just arbitrary.